# How to add list view row on the top if list view has dynamic data getting from server in android

Tags: android

I have a custom list view that is getting data from server and changing its content after each 3 seconds.this list view i am using for showing the visitor list who are visiting the site.Each row of list contains ipaddress,statustext,duration time,noofvisit and button text and data is updating and changing in list this part is working fine.For showing this list i am writing custom adapter for this.

Actually i have an issue i have to show the row on the top if status text is chat request.How can i do this?can anyone help me?

Actually i am using tabhost after login screen tabhost contains four tabs.First used  for monitoring window that show list of visitor and other are chat window,operatorlist and controls.

As i define above if i got status chat request then that row should appear on the top and will contains two button Accept and deny and on accept button click a window will open for chat and deny will use for refusing chat.

Can anyone help me for solving this issue?

my code is following

public  class BaseActivity extends Activity  {

```
private ListView list =null;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1010;
public static Timer timer = new Timer();
private  String response;
protected Dialog m_ProgressDialog;
String[] operatorList,operatorDetail,operatordetail,tempoperatordata;
String[] noofvisitors,opt;
private static final String DEB_TAG = "Error Message";
public static ArrayList<String> SessionText,IPText,DurationText,StatusText;
private ArrayList<String> NoOfVisit,ButtonText;
private int sizeoflist;
private String IP;
Context context;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
public static String from,sessionid,id,text,iptext,status,temo;
private int position,noofchat;
private boolean IsSoundEnable,IsChatOnly;
private Button logout;

NotificationManager notificationManager;



final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
private String url;

private Handler handler; 





public void TimerMethod()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer
    //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

    //We call the method that will work with the UI
    //through the runOnUiThread method.
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

} 

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               
        try{

            getVisitorDetailFromServer();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            Log.i("UPDATE", "Handler called");

            list.invalidateViews();
            playSound3();


        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", "error");
        }


    }


};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visitor);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list01);

    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogout);

    //list.addView("chat request", 0);





    //-----------------Making the object of arrayList----------------

    SessionText = new ArrayList<String>();
    IPText = new ArrayList<String>();
    DurationText = new ArrayList<String>();
    StatusText = new ArrayList<String>();
    NoOfVisit = new ArrayList<String>();
    ButtonText = new ArrayList<String>();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        IsSoundEnable = Controls.IsSoundEnable;
        IsChatOnly = Controls.IsChatOnly;
        IsSoundEnable = extras.getBoolean("IsSoundOnly", Controls.IsSoundEnable);
        IsChatOnly= extras.getBoolean("IsCOnlyhat", Controls.IsChatOnly);
        extras.getString("From");
        position=extras.getInt("Position");


    }



}



@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();


    //------------Getting the visitor detail-------------------------

    try{
        getVisitorDetailFromServer();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 7000); 




    //---------------When user click on logout button-----------------------------------


    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{
                logoutFromServer();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }


    });


}

private void playSound3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newvisitors);

    mp.start();

}




//----------------------------Getting the detail from server of monitoring window-------------------------


private void getVisitorDetailFromServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_AllOnline;
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("nvar","Y");
    postParameters.put("conly", "N");


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );

                //System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                String result = response;
                result = response;

                String delimiter1 = "<ln>";
                String delimiter2 = "<blk>";

                String[] temp = result.split(delimiter2);
                operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);
                if(temp.length==7){
                    String visitorString = temp[0];
                    String strSound = temp[3];
                    String strCSRmsgOrChatTrans = temp[4];
                    String stroperator = temp[5];
                    String strvisitor = temp[1];

                    visitorString =  visitorString.trim();
                    if(!(visitorString.equals(""))||(visitorString.equalsIgnoreCase("No Visitors online")||(visitorString.equalsIgnoreCase("No Users Online")))){
                        operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);
                        //sizeoflist =operatorDetail.length;
                    }
                    else{

                        sizeoflist = 0;
                    }

                }

                else{

                    sizeoflist = operatorDetail.length;
                }

                //System.out.println("operatordetail length"+operatorDetail.length);


                System.out.println("firstresponse================"+operatorDetail[0]);
                if(operatorDetail[0].equalsIgnoreCase("logout")){
                    sizeoflist = 0;
                    System.exit(0);
                    finish();
                }

                if(temp[0].equalsIgnoreCase("No Users Online")){
                   if(temp[1].equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                       sizeoflist =0;
                }
                   else if(temp[1].length()>0){
                       sizeoflist = 0;
                   }
                   else if(temp[0].equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        sizeoflist = 0;
                    }
                    sizeoflist =0;
                }
                else{
                    sizeoflist =operatorDetail.length;
                }





                //operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);

                //--------Getting the size of the list---------------------

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //playsound3();
                        noofchat =0;

                        list.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(BaseActivity.this));

                        list.getDrawingCache(false);
                        list.invalidateViews();
                        list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        list.requestFocus(0);
                        list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                        //list.setSelected(true);


                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }


                        });


                    }


                });
            }

            else {

                //ShowAlert();
            }


        }
    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();




}


//--------------------When internet connection is failed show alert

private void ShowAlert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Live2Support");
    alert.setMessage("Internet Connection failed");
    alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //startActivity(new Intent(CreateAccount.this,CreateAccount.class));
            alert.dismiss();

        }
    });

    alert.show();
}


//------------------------Getting the notification of no.of visitor on the site---------------------------

private void triggerNotification() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CharSequence title = "No Of visitors";
    CharSequence message = "New visit";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, noofvisitors[0], System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, L2STest.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(BaseActivity.this, title, noofvisitors[0], pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    playsound4();

}

public void completed()    {
    //remove the notification from the status bar
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}


private void playsound4() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newvisitsound);

    mp.start();

}



//-----------------Logout from server--------------------

private void logoutFromServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String url ="http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_LOGOUT;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try{
        postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
        postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);

                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );

                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);







            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //  notificationManager.cancelAll();]


                        System.out.println(response);
                        showAlert1();

                        //getSharedPreferences(Main.PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
                        Log.e(DEB_TAG, response);
                        //System.exit(0);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,Main.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //closeHandler();

                    }


                });
            }


        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();


}



//----------------------Logout alert when user click on logout button------------------


private void showAlert1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "You have Successfully logout.";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 200, 200);
    toast.show();
}



//-------------------Play sound3 when any new user visit----------------


private void playsound3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newvisitors);

    mp.start();

}


//------------------The adapter class------------------------------


private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;




    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        SessionText.clear(); 
        IPText.clear(); 
        DurationText.clear(); 
        StatusText.clear(); 
        NoOfVisit.clear(); 
        ButtonText.clear(); 



    }


    public int getCount() {
        return sizeoflist;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.IP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ip);
            holder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            holder.status =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.noOfVisit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NoOfvisit);
            holder.invite =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnjoin);
            holder.deny = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btndeny);
            //holder.accept = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnaccept);


            holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.invite.setId(position);
            holder.invite.setTag(position);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        String result = response;

        String delimiter = "<fld>";
        String delimiter1 = "<ln>";



        for(int i=0;i<operatorDetail.length;i++){
            if(operatorDetail!=null){

                //System.out.println("Operator res=============="+operatorDetail[i]);


                operatorList = operatorDetail[i].split(delimiter);

                try{

                    if(operatorList[0]!=null){
                        SessionText.add(operatorList[0]);
                        sessionid = operatorList[0];
                    }
                    else{
                        onStart();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[1]!=null){
                        IPText.add(operatorList[1]);
                        iptext = operatorList[1];
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[4]!=null){
                        DurationText.add(operatorList[4]);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[3]!=null){
                        StatusText.add(operatorList[3]);
                        status = operatorList[3];
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[2]!=null){
                        NoOfVisit.add(operatorList[2]);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //ButtonText.add(operatorList[6]);




                try{
                    if(IPText!=null){

                        holder.IP.setText(IPText.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(DurationText!=null){

                        holder.duration.setText(DurationText.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(StatusText!=null){

                        holder.status.setText(StatusText.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try{
                    if(NoOfVisit!=null){
                        holder.noOfVisit.setText(NoOfVisit.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




                //----------------If status is chat request then check for this-----------------

                try{
                    if(StatusText.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("chat request")){
                        //playsound();
                        playsound();
                        holder.deny.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.invite.setText("Accept");
                        holder.deny.setText("Deny");
                        convertView.bringToFront();
                        convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        convertView.setSelected(true);
                        //convertView.setFocusable(true);
                        convertView.requestFocus();
                        convertView.clearFocus();


                        holder.invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                holder.invite.setText("Join");
                                holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                try{
                                    chatRequest(IPText.get(position), SessionText.get(position));
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,Chat1.class);
                                i.putExtra("ID", id);
                                i.putExtra("Position",position);
                                i.putExtra("From", from);
                                try{
                                    i.putExtra("SessionText",SessionText.get(position));
                                    i.putExtra("IPTEXT",IPText.get(position));
                                    i.putExtra("StatusText",StatusText.get(position));
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else{
                        holder.invite.setText("Invite");
                        holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //---------------------When user click on invite Button---------------------


                        holder.invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                timer.purge();

                                try{
                                    if(SessionText!=null){
                                        callToServer(SessionText.get(position));
                                    }

                                    else{

                                        System.out.println("null");

                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){

                                    e.printStackTrace();


                                }

                            }
                        });


                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }







                //-----------------------------When user click on deny button------------------------

                holder.deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        timer.purge();
                        try{
                            if(SessionText.get(position)!=null){
                                refuseToServer(SessionText.get(position));
                                holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("null");
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }




                });


                //-----------When user click on the listiview row-----------------------

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        timer.purge();

                        if(SessionText!=null&&IPText!=null){
                            try{
                                Intent i=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,VisitorDetail.class);
                                i.putExtra("ID", id);
                                i.putExtra("Position",position);
                                i.putExtra("From", from);
                                i.putExtra("SessionText", sessionid);
                                i.putExtra("IPTEXT",iptext);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        else{

                            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                public void run() {
                                    TimerMethod();
                                }

                            }, 0, 5000); 
                        }



                    }});


            }

        }

        operatorDetail=null; 
        operatorList=null; 


        operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);



        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView IP;
        TextView duration;
        Button deny;
        TextView status;
        TextView noOfVisit;
        Button invite;
        Button accept;
    }
}


//------------------Play sound when user click on invite button-------------------------

private void playSound2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.invite);

    mp.start();

}


//---------------When any chat request come-----------------

private void playsound() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chatinvitation);

    mp.start();

}



//------------When user click on deny button---------------------


private void refuseToServer(String sessionid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //final String url = "http://sa.live2support.com/cpn/wz-action.php?";
    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_ACTION;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParameters.put("action","refuse");
    postParameters.put("csesid", sessionid);


    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );


                System.out.println("Deny Chat response:"+response);


                System.out.println("Deny chat Success"+IP); 


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        System.out.println("response================="+IP);

                        showAlert(IP);

                    }



                });
            }


        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}



//---------------------When user click on invite button-----------------------


private void callToServer(String session) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_ACTION;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParameters.put("action","cinvt");
    postParameters.put("csesid", session);

    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );


                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                IP = response;
                System.out.println("the resultant ip ===================="+IP);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        playSound2();

                        System.out.println("response================="+IP);

                        showAlert(IP);

                    }



                });
            }


        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}

//------------------Show invitation alert----------------------

private void showAlert(String ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Invitation sent to "+ip;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 50, 50);
    toast.show();
}


//-----------------When in response we get the chat request--------------------------

private void chatRequest(String iptext, String sessionid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_ONCHATREQUEST;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();


    postParameters.put("csesid", sessionid);
    postParameters.put("ipaddr", iptext);

    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("join", "Y");


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );


                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                IP = response;
                System.out.println("the resultant ip ===================="+IP);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        playSound2();

                        System.out.println("response================="+response);

                        showAlert(IP);

                    }

                });
            }

        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}



public void onNotifiyDataSetChanged(){
    super.notifyAll();
}




@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,Main.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);          
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

what can i do for setting the row that has chat request on the top?Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to narrow down your question somewhat, it's *way* too long for it to be constructive.

Comment: might be this way http://pastebin.com/fz3DsAya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> userList = your list of data
            // other list also 
            //userListA
            //userListB
            ArrayList<String> tempUserList = new ArrayList<String>();
            // other list also 
            //tempuserListA
            //tempuserListB
            String text = "ChatRequest";
            // to add CharRequest at top
            for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++)
            {
                if(userList.get(i).equals(text))
                {
                    tempUserList.add(userList.get(i));
                    //tempuserlistA.add(userlistA.get(i));
                    //tempuserlistB.add(userlistB.get(i));
                }

            }
            // to add other entry
            for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++)
            {
                if(!userList.get(i).equals(text))
                {
                    tempUserList.add(userList.get(i));
                    //tempuserlistA.add(userlistA.get(i));
                    //tempuserlistB.add(userlistB.get(i));
                }

            }

            //now temp list are you original list to use
            userList = tempUserList;
            //userListA = tempuserlistA;
            //userListB = tempuserlistB;

            // and then call your adapter with the arraylists
```

Comment: thanks soni for your help.this code working for me but after some change i am using some part of your code.........

Comment: ok..sure..was easy to understand the problem because of out chat..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList holding your Data for the ListView and add an item at the beginning of the list by: myArrayList.add(0, newItem).
Below an example Adapter which can do this:

```
public class PlaylistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Playlist> entries;

    public PlaylistAdapter(Context context, List<Playlist> entries) {
        this.context = context;
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public void add(Playlist item) {
        if (entries.contains(item))
            return;
        entries.add(item);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void add(int index, Playlist item) {
        if (entries.contains(item))
            return;
        entries.add(index, item);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Playlist getItem(int arg0) {
        return entries.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // inflate the layout you want to use for a single entry row
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlists_adapter_entry,
                    null);
        }
        // fetches the current item
        Playlist playlist = getItem(position);

        // fill the entry layout with data
        ImageView cover = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.playlist_adapter_entry_cover);
        cover.setImageBitmap(playlist.getCover());

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.playlist_adapter_entry_title);
        title.setText(playlist.getTitle());     
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: will this work if data is continuing changing.................

Comment: Yep. Just call "add(0, myItem)"